# Yaml encoding issues after upgrading Ruby to 1.9.3 from 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, character-encoding, yaml, upgrade, ruby-1.9.3

Maybe you can help with a Yaml encoding I have.

We have an application that stores some settings serialized in a database as a Yaml string, for example:

```
---
quantity_units: Stunden,Tage, Monate, Pauschal, Jahre, GB, MB, StÃ¼ck, Seite, SMS
categories: Shirts
number_schema: P-[Y4]-[CY3]
```

We are in a process of moving from Ruby 1.8.7 to Ruby 1.9.3, and the Yaml parsing library has changed between the versions, leaving us with decoded strings like this from `Stück` to `StÃ¼ck`.

I only want to know how could properly convert these strings into unicode, and I'll take care of the rest.

I don't know which encoding was using in 1.8.7 Yaml parser.

Comment: Which encoding did you use to read the YAML file? And which encoding does the `StÃ¼ck` string in ruby have?

Comment: default UTF-8 ruby 1.9.3 encoding; `> "StÃ¼ck".encoding # => #<Encoding:UTF-8>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like utf8 read as iso-8895-1, and interpreted as utf-8 by
the ruby adapter. You might want to check your current locale and the
locale of the database server. Also see what happens if you access the
data directly via console, and check the encoding there as well. It
looks like utf-8 on the database, but gets interpreted as iso-8859-1
somewhere in between.

If nothing helps, there's a snippet to pass your data through (and
write it back).

```
 "StÃ¼ck".encode('iso-8859-1').force_encoding('utf-8') # I've no idea what I'm doing.
 # => "Stück"
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you @Tass, I write a strange method like your "# I've no idea what I'm doing."

I have an  application in rails 2.3 under ruby 1.8 which share a Mysql database with rails 3.2 and ruby 1.9

On rails 2.2
When i save a serialized Array, sometimes i can see in mysql "binary!" or my string in wrong format, and so, when i display text with rails 3.2 i got strange behavior.

I wrote a method to handle this problem (I hope we will migrate rails 2.3):

```
def self.decode(words)
  temp_name = words || ''
  temp_name_encoding = temp_name.encoding

  if temp_name_encoding == Encoding::ASCII_8BIT
    return temp_name.encode('ASCII-8BIT').force_encoding('utf-8')
  elsif temp_name_encoding == Encoding::UTF_8
    return temp_name.encode('iso-8859-1').force_encoding('utf-8')
  else
    return temp_name
  end
rescue Encoding::UndefinedConversionError
  temp_name
end
```